# Continuous numbering of a the retrieved data in an extra column

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, unique, distinct

I want to get a numbered cursor when I use a SELECT DISTINCT query.

Table:

```
| _id | Name  |
| 1   | Jones | 
| 2   | Smith | 
| 3   | Jones | 
| 4   | Taylor| 
| 5   | Brown | 
| 6   | Brown | 
| 7   | Brown |
```

What I want to get a cursor like this:

```
| _id | Name  |
| 1   | Jones | 
| 2   | Smith | 
| 3   | Taylor| 
| 4   | Brown |
```

I tried a lot but it wasn't working.
Sometimes there were no unique values and sometimes I get the following error when I selected an Item:

```
08-22 22:18:15.413: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1053): java.lang.IllegalStateException: this should only be called when the cursor is valid
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are looking for a thing called `ranking`  sadly I don't know the SQLite syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest method is to use a temporary table:

```
'create temporary table bat as select distinct name from yourtable; 
 select rowid, * from bat ; '
```

Comment: Hi that sounds good. I tried the following: `"create temporary table bat as select distinct "+col +" from "+table+";"+ 
         "select _id, * from bat ; ` but I get the exception that _id doesn't exists... And I tried:`"create temporary table bat (_id integer primary key autoincrement, item as select distinct "+col+" from "+table+");"+ 
 "select _id,"+col+" from bat;"` But it didn't worked,too.